# Popover in ionic not working but runs fine in Codepen

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to implement the $ionicPopover but for some reason it won't work in my project. But when I run it in [Codepen](http://codepen.io/GY22/pen/LpqzOK) it does. Anybody can tell me why?

My html code:

```
<div ng-controller="SettingsCtrl">
<ion-view view-title="Instellingen">
    <ion-content >

        <div class="padding">
            <p class="textContact">Title</p>
            <p class="textContact">Title 2</p>
        </div>

        <div>   
           <p class="textContact" ng-click="openPopover($event)"><a href="#">Taal</a></p>
        </div>

    </ion-content>

    <script id="popover.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-popover-view>
        <ion-content>
          <div class="list">
            <a class="item">
              Lorem Ipsum
            </a>
          </div>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-popover-view>
    </script>

</ion-view>
</div>
```

My controller code:

```
angular.module('ChemicarSettings.controllers', [])

.controller('SettingsCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopover){

    $scope.openPopover = function ($event) {
        $ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('popover.html', {
            scope: $scope
        }).then(function(popover) {
            $scope.popover = popover;
            $scope.popover.show($event);
        });
    }; 

})
```

Comment: Well in the code pen you are referencing has a direct registration of the controller to `myApp`. Is there perhaps a problem with registering your module to `ChimicarSettings.controllers`, perhaps a typo with the module name or an issue with that module being registered to another?

Comment: no typos otherwise chrome developer would throw an error and i have no errors

Answer (score 0):

How about checking the app.js? Did you add the ChemicarSettings.controllers to the angular.module line in the app.js? For instance..

```
angular.module('ChemicarSettings', ['ionic','ChemicarSettings.controllers'])
```

Also add "ionic" in the first line of the ChemicarSettings.controllers:

```
angular.module('ChemicarSettings.controllers', ['ionic'])
```

Comment: Yes those are already added. i just didn't put them in the code cause it seems obvious.